# Trouble with a positional parameter

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to create an object per this article

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/user-and-shared-mailboxes/cannot-access-mailbox

However when I run my code I get an error message but I am not sure why,

```
New-Remotemailbox -Name "John Smith RB Archive" -Alias jsmith_rb_archive -UserPrincipalName jsmith_rb_archive@contoso.com -Remoteroutingaddress "jsmith_rb_archive@contosos.onmicrosoft.com" -Shared
```

The error is as follows:

**A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-Shared'.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-RemoteMailbox], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,New-RemoteMailbox**

Any advice you can offer would be greatly appreciated. Also please note that I am using the EMS for Exchange 2010 as that is what our on premise mailserver is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-remotemailbox?view=exchange-ps) clearly states:

> This switch is available only in Exchange 2013 CU21 or later and Exchange 2016 CU10 or later.

Also, the article you quoted says it applies to:

> Exchange Online, Exchange Server 2016 Enterprise Edition, Exchange Server 2016 Standard Edition, Exchange Server 2013 Enterprise, Exchange Server 2013 Standard Edition